# Spring MVC:How to get file path into Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have following folder structure:

```
ProjectFolder/images/some images
```

In the same folder

```
ProjectFolder/WEB-INF/classes/com/xyz/here is java file of controller.
```

How can I get the image path in the controller?

Please, help.
Thanks  :)

Comment: Why can't you just use `/images/some images`?

Comment: I am tried same but FileNotFound exception occurred.

Comment: FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/images/abort.png");

Comment: This won't work. You can't use a FileInputStream in a web context like this. Get hold of another stream from elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If its a web context may be something like this could help

```
InputStream is = null ;
is = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/someimage.jpg");
```

or may be something like this:

```
InputStream is = null ;
String realPath  = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/someimage.jpg");
is = new FileInputStream(realPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your image path in properties file.

store that property file in your classpath.

now access that property in your controller class like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
/*to access your filename.properties file */
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));

String  sServerLocation = properties.getProperty("server.upload.docs.path");
```

note that you should use escape charater in your property file like :

```
server.upload.docs.path=D:\\JDIS3\\DOCS\\
```